# Image bigger than screen is cropped when animated

Tags: android, rotation, scale, android-imageview, android-animation

I need to rotate a wheel image, bigger than screen (that's a must).

The problem is that the android:scaleType="center" is necessary to display a image bigger than screen without being scaled, and this same tag crops the image when rotated (see screenshot below)

[image]

Here is the code of my layout :

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/wheel_img"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wheel_test" />
```

my activity :

```
ImageView wheel_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wheel_img);
wheel_img.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation));
```

and the anim/rotation.xml

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="30"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? This is quite urgent actually!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This is the trick that I use

use framelayout

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/wheel_image"
           android:layout_width="image width"
           android:layout_height="image height"
           android:src="@drawable/wheel_test"
           android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

works like a charm.

and that's my first contribution here. hope it works with you

Answer (score 0):

adding your view inside scroll-view does the trick

```
         <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_light_streak"
                    android:layout_width="500dp"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"                        
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/wheel_test" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```